# SVN Timing Out on Initial Commit

Tags: svn

I've been trying to get SVN working on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ w/ a NAS attached.  I've got it mostly working (I'm able to commit small projects/tests).  However, I'm trying to commit a project that's roughly 2.4GB in size (it takes roughly 2.5 hours to run the import).

On the initial commit/import Tortoise successfully goes through all of the files and then says "Committing transaction..." for roughly 10 minutes and then ends with errors.  I've looked at permissions, I've deleted/removed the repository on the NAS and re-created the project with permissions and retried with slightly different settings many times... and I've edited several timeout settings (as seen below).  I'm pretty baffled as to why this keeps failing.  (FYI - Most of my edits are from other posts I've found with similar (but not the same) issues I found on the web).

Below are the errors, configurations, and system information on the matter.  Could someone help me figure this out?  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Tortoise SVN Committ error:

```
Connection timed out
Additional errors:
Unexpected server error 500 'Internal Server Error' on
 '/svn/LinkedBound/!svn/txn/0-0'
```

Apache2 error.log:

```
[Sun Jul 12 12:38:18.450162 2020] [dav:error] [pid 901:tid 1905226784] [client 192.168.1.92:57605] Could not DELETE /svn/LinkedBound/!svn/txn/0-0.  [500, #0]
[Sun Jul 12 12:38:18.454529 2020] [dav:error] [pid 901:tid 1905226784] [client 192.168.1.92:57605] could not abort transaction.  [500, #2]
[Sun Jul 12 12:38:18.454591 2020] [dav:error] [pid 901:tid 1905226784] [client 192.168.1.92:57605] Transaction '0-0' cleanup failed  [500, #2]
[Sun Jul 12 12:38:18.454629 2020] [dav:error] [pid 901:tid 1905226784] [client 192.168.1.92:57605] Can't remove '/home/pi/myNAS/Projects/GameDev/repos/Unity/LinkedBound/db/transactions/0-0.txn/node._7f.0'  [500, #2]
[Sun Jul 12 12:38:18.454666 2020] [dav:error] [pid 901:tid 1905226784] [client 192.168.1.92:57605] Can't remove file '/home/pi/myNAS/Projects/GameDev/repos/Unity/LinkedBound/db/transactions/0-0.txn/node._7f.0': No such file or directory  [500, #2]
[Sun Jul 12 12:38:18.612336 2020] [dav:error] [pid 903:tid 1894757408] [client 192.168.1.92:51135] Could not MERGE resource "/svn/LinkedBound/!svn/txn/0-0" into "/svn/LinkedBound".  [500, #0]
[Sun Jul 12 12:38:18.612503 2020] [dav:error] [pid 903:tid 1894757408] [client 192.168.1.92:51135] An error occurred while committing the transaction.  [500, #160014]
[Sun Jul 12 12:38:18.612553 2020] [dav:error] [pid 903:tid 1894757408] [client 192.168.1.92:51135] Reference to non-existent node '_fhr.0.t0-0' in filesystem '/home/pi/myNAS/Projects/GameDev/repos/Unity/LinkedBound/db'  [500, #160014]
```

Tortoise SVN Config (%appdata%\subversion\config) alterations:

```
http-timeout = 3600000
```

~/.subversion/servers alterations:

```
[global]

http-timeout = 3600000
```

Permissions set:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/pi/myNAS/Projects/GameDev/repos/ && sudo chmod a+x /etc/apache2
```

dav_svn.conf settings:

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
# Set to 10h.
Timeout 36000

SVNCompressionLevel 5
SVNInMemoryCacheSize 16384
SVNCacheTextDeltas On
SVNCacheFullTexts On
SVNAllowBulkUpdates Prefer

<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /home/pi/myNAS/Projects/GameDev/repos/Unity
  SVNListParentPath On
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repo"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
  # Allow large request
  LimitXMLRequestBody 0
 </Location>
```

WD My Cloud EX4100 /etc/exports setting:

```
"/nfs/Projects" *(rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_wdelay,insecure,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
```

NAS Information:

```
WD My Cloud EX4100
Firmware: 2.31.204
```

Tortoise SVN Version

```
1.14 (r28864)
```

SVN OS

```
Linux 4.19.118-v7+ #1311 SMP Mon Apr 27 14:21:24 BST 2020 armv7l
GNU/Linux Distributor ID: Raspbian 
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 
Release:        10 
Codename:       buster
```

My PC:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900]
```

Comment: It has been a few years since I've administrated an SVN server but IIRC, Apache by default has a limit to how large a request you can send to it. This is changeable via the `LimitRequestBody` directive(s). Not saying this _is_ the issue, but something to check into.

Comment: Alroc, thanks for the reply... Sorry it took me so long to respond back.  I ended up dropping SVN and using GIT.  SVN just doesn't seem well optimized to run in an ARM environment... or there just isn't enough good documentation on getting it to run correctly in said environment.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from SVN to GIT.

I was unable to commit files larger than 100MB, I couldn't find good documentation and/or I couldn't find anyone who could get SVN to work on an RPi 3 B+.

GIT seems to work pretty well on the RPi3B+.